# sed or other - remove specific html tag text from file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Trying to remove a specific html tag from a file.

Question:

1. How do I get the desired result?
2. Should I be using the sed command for desired results?

file: test1.txt

```
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

sed

```
sed -e 's/<\/body>\\n<\/html>\\n//' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Desired result in test2.txt

```
Hello World
```

Actual

```
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cross site reference of how `sed` can recognize new lines is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384775

Comment: You're getting a few answers that would remove either tag even if the other didn't exist near it, is that desirable or not?

Comment: For this use case as long as those two tags are removed it is desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be using the sed command for desired results?

Actually `grep` suits it better with:

```bash
grep -Ev '</(body|html)>' file

Hello World
```

If you want to remove specific `<body>\n</html>\n` string only then use this `sed` that would work with any version of `sed`:

```bash
sed '/<\/body>/{N; /<\/html>/ {N; s~</body>\n</html>\n~~;};}' file

Hello World
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples in `awk`(if ok) you could try following. Using `RS` and setting it to `^$` here. Also using `match` function of `awk`. So basically matching the string which is having new line in it and printing everything before and after it as per requirement.

```
awk -v RS="^$" '
match($0,/(^|\n)<\/body>\n<\/html>/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed, you can use a `-z` option to match newlines:

```bash
sed -z -i 's#</body>\n</html>##g' file
```

Note that `#` is chosen as a regex delimiter char to avoid overescaping `/`. Also, `-i` makes changes directly into the input file.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/IkqyYY):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Hello World
</body>
</html>'
sed -z 's#</body>\n</html>##g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '\~^</(body|html)>~d' input_file
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant using sed:

```
sed '/<\/body>/{N;/\n<\/html>/d}' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Match `</body>` and pull the next line into the pattern space using `N`. Then match on a newline followed by `</html>`.

If that matches, use `d` to delete what is in the pattern space.

The content of file *'test2.txt'*

```
Hello World
```